# Tablesorter 2.17.7 CSS not working?

Tags: php, css, tablesorter

As the title says, CSS wont apply to my table.. I have all the JS functionality but CSS is not working...
I have 3 folders: Includes, Images and tablesorter. All other pages are outside of those folders (project root)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Images/icon.ico"/>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Condensed:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

**<link href="tablesorter/css/theme.green.css" rel="stylesheet" />**
<script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/js/widgets/widget-pager.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
```

I'm including header.php in other files and everything is working besides that tablesorter's CSS..

This is part of code where I apply the tablesorter.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#tablica").tablesorter()}
        );
</script>

<table id="table" class="tablesorter">
```

Table has thead->tr->th and tbody->tr->td and it is filled from database... 
And once more: **I have Javascript functionality but none of the CSS properties apply..**

Answer (score 1):

By default, the "tablesorter-default" class name is applied to the table. If you want to apply the green theme, you'll need to load the "theme.green.css" file (as you have shown above) and set the `theme` option:

```
$("#tablica").tablesorter({
  theme: 'green'
});
```

or just add a "tablesorter-green" class name to the table:

```
<table id="tablica" class="tablesorter-green">
```

If you want to apply a jQuery UI or Bootstrap theme, you'll need to use the "uitheme" widget, and change a few additional options different from their default settings. Make sure to load the "theme.jui.css" or "theme.bootstrap.css" file as well:

```
$("#tablica").tablesorter({
  theme : 'jui', // theme "jui" or "bootstrap"
  headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}',

  // uitheme widget is contained within the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js file
  widgets : ['uitheme', 'zebra']
});
```